# Simple concurrency implemented in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency

**Purpose of the question**: learn more about ways to implement concurrency in Python / experimenting.

**Context**: I want to count all of the words in all of the files that match a particular pattern. The idea is that I can invoke the function `count_words('/foo/bar/*.txt')` and all of the words (i.e., strings separated by one or more whitespace characters) will be counted.

In the implementation I am looking for ways to implement `count_words` using concurrency. So far I managed to use `multiprocessing` and `asyncio`.

What do you think of these two approaches? 
Do you see alternative approaches to do the same task?
What about the code style, should I implement a dedicated class for each approach?

I did not use `threading` as I noticed the performance improvement was not that impressive due to the limitation of the Python GIL.

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import time
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint


def count_words(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return sum(len(line.split()) for line in f)


async def count_words_for_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return sum(len(line.split()) for line in f)


def async_count_words(path, glob_pattern):
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        print("Entering event loop")
        for file in list(path.glob(glob_pattern)):
            result = event_loop.run_until_complete(count_words_for_file(file))
            print(result)
    finally:
        event_loop.close()


def multiprocess_count_words(path, glob_pattern):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        results = pool.map(count_words, list(path.glob(glob_pattern)))
        pprint(results)


def sequential_count_words(path, glob_pattern):
    for file in list(path.glob(glob_pattern)):
        print(count_words(file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    benchmark = []
    path = Path("../data/gutenberg/")
    # no need for benchmark on sequential_count_words, it is very slow!
    # sequential_count_words(path, "*.txt")

    start = time.time()
    async_count_words(path, "*.txt")
    benchmark.append(("async version", time.time() - start))

    start = time.time()
    multiprocess_count_words(path, "*.txt")
    benchmark.append(("multiprocess version", time.time() - start))

    print(*benchmark)
```

For simulating large quantity of files, I downloaded some books from Project Gutenberg ([https://gutenberg.org/](https://www.gutenberg.org/)) and used the following command to create several duplicates of the same file.

```
for i in {000..99}; do cp 56943-0.txt $(openssl rand -base64 12)-$i.txt; done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
async def count_words_for_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return sum(len(line.split()) for line in f)
```

Just making this function async won't bring you any benefit. `asyncio` can improve performance only if you're running multiple operations that can be parallelized. Usual case is when you're running multiple downloads: `asyncio` will do some job instead of idle waiting answer from network and through that bring you benefit.

In your case almost everything faces CPU (splitting lines) and disk I/O (reading files). For can be parallelized throught processes only (due to GIL), for second you can use threads (since GIL doesn't affect disk I/O). In both cases you can use asyncio to rule the process with [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor).

Read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357233/when-to-use-and-when-not-to-use-python-3-5-await/33399896) for general explanation and few examples.